# Dovecot - cannot move email out of inbox

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Background ... I had an HDD go bad in an Ubuntu 20 server. I build an Ubuntu 20 server in a completely new machine, then moved as much as I could from the errored HDD to the brand new RAID.

Part of the move was postfix/dovecot. The postfix part of the move was successful, mail is coming in and being added to the correct mail file inboxes.

The dovecot part of the move wasn't quite so successful though. All email is being shown correctly in the inbox, mail filtering with Thunderbird appears to work but with a BUT.
What happens is the mail gets moved to the correct folder and disappears from the inbox. Selecting the mailbox with the moved email shows the email in the folder until the inbox is selected again. Then all moved mail shows up again as new BUT there is a copy of the email still in the target folder. Running the filters again will move (copy) the files back to the correct folder, causing multiple copies of the same email in the target folder.

All efforts to find an issue show that the problem is restricted to emails in the inbox.

The issue is apparent not only with Thunderbird filtering but also when using the delete key. The only way to delete email is to avoid moving the email to the deleted folder by using Shift + delete.

Configuration of dovecot

```
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo dovecot -n
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.4.0-96-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS ext4
# Hostname: wilma.example.com
auth_debug = yes
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = plain
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot/debug.log
disable_plaintext_auth = no
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot/info.log
log_path = /var/log/dovecot/warnings.log
mail_access_groups = mail
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = mbox:/var/imap/%d/%n/mail/:INBOX=/var/virtual/%d/%n:LAYOUT=fs
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = nobody
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = passwd
}
passdb {
  args = username_format=%n /etc/virtual/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge copy mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap-postlogin {
  executable = script-login /etc/dovecot/lastLogin.sh
  unix_listener imap-postlogin {
    user = root
  }
}
service imap {
  executable = imap imap-postlogin
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/Email_cert/fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
verbose_ssl = yes
```

File system snapshot ...

```
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo find . ! -user nobody -o ! -group mail -ls
-- no output --
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo ls -l example.com/mike/mail/Facebook
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody mail 16689445 Jan 25 11:26 example.com/mike/mail/Facebook
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo ls -ld example.com/mike/mail
drwxrwxr-x 13 nobody mail 4096 Jan 25 12:03 example.com/mike/mail
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo ls -ld example.com/mike
drwxrwxr-x 3 nobody mail 4096 Jan 23 21:19 example.com/mike
mike@wilma:/var/imap$ sudo ls -ld example.com
drwx-wx--x 5 nobody mail 4096 Jan 23 21:20 example.com
```

I'm not too sure what other information would be useful to you

TIA
Mike

Tried this but it didn't have the desired result, emails still popped back with 2 seconds of being deleted ...

```
root@wilma:/var/imap# doveadm -v -D force-resync -u mike@example.com INBOX
Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_acl_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_acl_plugin.so: undefined symbol: acl_user_module (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_expire_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_expire_plugin.so: undefined symbol: expire_set_deinit (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_quota_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_quota_plugin.so: undefined symbol: quota_user_module (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_sieve_plugin.so
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_fts_lucene_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib20_doveadm_fts_lucene_plugin.so: undefined symbol: lucene_index_iter_deinit (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_fts_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib20_doveadm_fts_plugin.so: undefined symbol: fts_user_get_language_list (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_mail_crypt_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/libdoveadm_mail_crypt_plugin.so: undefined symbol: mail_crypt_box_get_pvt_digests (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(mike@example.com): Started userdb lookup
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Connecting
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Client connected (fd=10)
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(mike@example.com): auth USER input: mike@example.com 
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: auth-master: userdb lookup(mike@example.com): Finished userdb lookup (username=mike@example.com )
doveadm(mike@example.com)<59647><>: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/=yes
doveadm(mike@example.com): Debug: Effective uid=65534, gid=8, home=
doveadm(mike@example.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=mbox:/var/imap/example.com/mike/mail/:INBOX=/var/virtual/example.com/mike:LAYOUT=fs
doveadm(mike@example.com): Debug: fs: root=/var/imap/example.com/mike/mail, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/virtual/example.com/mike, alt=
doveadm(mike@example.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Mailbox opened because: force-resync
doveadm(mike@example.com): Debug: auth-master: conn unix:/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb: Disconnected: Connection closed (fd=10)
```

Log files only show the following

```
Jan 27 09:20:49 imap(mike@example.com)<60062><0OOA3IHWZozAqAGO>: Debug: Mailbox Trash: Mailbox opened because: UID move
Jan 27 09:20:49 imap(mike@example.com)<60062><0OOA3IHWZozAqAGO>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: UID 229597: Opened mail because: copying
Jan 27 09:20:49 imap(mike@example.com)<60062><0OOA3IHWZozAqAGO>: Debug: Mailbox INBOX: UID 229597: Opened mail because: full mail
```

Tried this to no avail ...

```
root@wilma:/var/imap/example.com# chmod -R o+w *
root@wilma:/var/imap/example.com# systemctl restart dovecot
```

Also tried unsubscribing from all folders. Deleted an email, it bounced back. Subscribed again, deleted again, email bounced back again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away overnight, apparently all by itself. I can't say for sure exactly which change I made was the one to fix the problem.